# activity in running app list after alarm

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, alarmmanager, alarm

I currently started developing for Android and ran into a problem.

I made a basic application in wich i can set a timer between 5 and 60 seconds. After a button press an Intent starts a PendingIntent wich will register an alarm in the Android AlarmManager.

I can simply set an alarm for 30 seconds, close my application, remove it from the running application list and wait. Eventhough my application is totally shut down, after 30 seconds my custom made activity with a simple view pops-up and i can stop my alarm.

The problem: even though i removed my APPLICATION from the running app list after i did set an alarm, after it goes of and i pressed the stop alarm button so the activity is closed i see my ACTIVITY in the running app list..... i can click on it and my basic custom made acticity pops-up again.

In the stop button onClick() i call finish() in the onStop() i call super.onStop()....

How to show my custom alarm activity with my stop alarm button and after stopping or snoozing DO NOT show it in the running app list?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `android:excludeFromRecents="true"` as an attribute for your activity `<activity />` tag in your manifest file.

Comment: Im not able to test it at the moment, i will tomorrow. Although it sounds unlikely to work... im not talking about a list with recent apps. Im talking about... open chrome and press home button, it will be still active in background. If you press the button, that all android devices have, to show running apps you see chrome and you are able to slide it away to close. Im talking about that list. Thx for fast response!!!

Comment: Thanks for clarifications, however, I've used this attribute and it does exactly what you want (at least, in my case) - removes the app from that list.

Comment: @Bas that list you're talking about, that's called "recents", just like Arkadiy said